# How to run script in Firefox when a tab was closed?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, greasemonkey

At our company we are using a web application with shared licenses. Unfortunately if someone simply closes the tab the application is running in it wont release the license lock. I am wondering whether it is possible to run/trigger a scipt when a Firefox tab is closed, so I could automatically release the licenses? I think greasemonkey might be able to do this, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is both `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.onunload`, which are used differently depending on the browser. You can assing them either by setting the window properties to functions, or using the `.addEventListener`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   // Do something
}
// OR
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   // Do something
}, false);
```

Usually, `onbeforeunload` is used if you need to stop the user from leaving the page (ex. the user is working on some unsaved data, so he/she should save before leaving).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way to add this code to the site source from client side?

Comment: Did you just mean you are developing an application, but don't have any access to the source code?

Comment: No, it is a ready application, we are just users. However the developers left out this feature, and we could save lot of money with it.

Comment: What kind of script will 'release' the license lock then?

Comment: I catch the close trigger, and then automatically click the logout button. At least thats the plan :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try to release locks in unload events, as Bcfm suggested in his answer, but what if browser or computer simply crashes? Or script takes too long to execute and gets killed by browser anyway?

Another approach would be to make the site constantly *ping* license server (i.e. every 10 seconds) so that lock is hold until there is no ping for proportional amount of time (i.e. 30 seconds). This way the license lock is freed in all cases.

Of course this may be not relevant to your scenario, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately, I can only manipulate the server from client side, so I don't have the resources to do this :(

Comment: Good suggestion! I guess the best solution would be to combine the both ways, probably with increasing the ping time so it won't last the server.